# Interfaces property name differs from class to class

Tags: c#, oop

Here`s the question.

```
public abstract class A {}
public class B:A 
{
    public TypeF FieldB;
}
public class C:A 
{
    public TypeG FieldC;
}
public class TypeF:A {  }
public class TypeG:A {  }
```

I want to have interface ex: ITypeFG and to implement it in B and C **BUT** to have properties names FieldB and FieldC

```
interface ITypeFG
{
    public A FieldFG;  //But i want to have names TypeF in A and TypeG in B
}
```

Can this be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

explicit interface implementation:

```
public class B : A, ITypeFG
{
    public TypeF FieldB { get; set; } // please don't expose public fields...
    A ITypeFG.FieldFG { get { return FieldB; } }
}
public class C : A, ITypeFG
{
    public TypeG FieldC { get; set; }
    A ITypeFG.FieldFG { get { return FieldC; } }
}
```

Note that if the interface has a setter, you'll need to cast:

```
public class B : A, ITypeFG
{
    public TypeF FieldB { get; set; }
    A ITypeFG.FieldFG { get { return FieldB; } set { FieldB = (TypeF)value; } }
}
public class C : A, ITypeFG
{
    public TypeG FieldC { get; set; }
    A ITypeFG.FieldFG { get { return FieldC; } set { FieldC = (TypeG)value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two points:

1. Interfaces in C# can't have fields, but they can have properties.
2. The desired feature isn't sensible: if clients would always have to know the "specific" name of the implemented interface-property to interact with an implementation, then it isn't much of an interface is it - it's little more than a marker.

As Marc Gravell suggests, a decent workaround is to use explicit implementations. If the client has a reference to the implementing object typed as the *interface*, they can use the "general" name of the property. If they have a specific reference (i.e. typed as the *implementing* type) , they can use the "specific" name (and won't be confused by the general name since they won't see it on IntelliSense, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should treat the field names as data along with A. That way you can keep a common interface and only vary the content of what is returned:

```
class Data
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public A Value {get;set;}

}

interface ITypeFG
{
    Data Field {get;}
}

class B : A, ITypeFG
{
    public Data Field 
    {
        get
        {
            return new Data {Name = "TypeF", Value = FieldB};
        }
    }
}


class C : A, ITypeFG
{
    public Data Field 
    {
        get
        {
            return new Data {Name = "TypeG", Value = FieldC};
        }
    }
}
```